# Custom user function undefined in Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function in my User model named: `userHasRole()`. It is public.
I can access this function in my blade view with `auth()->user()->userHasRole('Admin)`.
For example I can use it within my blade @if directive to check if the user has the admin role.

However when I call this function `auth()->user()->userHasRole('Admin)` from my UserController it gives me a error named: Undefined function userHasRole.

I have `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` at the top of my script.

Can anyone explain to me why this is? Am I not allowed to call custom functions that I created in my user model from my UserController?

I tried creating a user with: `$user = auth()->user()`.
Then I tried to call the function from that object like so `$user->userHasRole('Admin')` but I still get the red squiggly underline which says call to undefined method.

I also tried it with: `Auth::user()->userHasRole('Admin')` . But still the same red quiggly underline which says undefined method.

This is the function in my UserController:

```php
 public function authenticate(Request $request){
        $formFields = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if(auth()->attempt($formFields)){
            $request->session()->regenerate();
        
            if(auth()->user()->userHasRole('Admin')){
                return redirect('/admin');
            } else {
                return redirect('/activities');
            }
        }

        return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Ongeldige inloggegevens'])->onlyInput('email');
    }
```

--- Workaround ---
I managed to solve the problem by getting the user like this:

```php
if(auth()->attempt($formFields)){
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        
            if($user->userHasRole('Admin')){
                return redirect('admin');
            } else {
                return redirect('/activities');
            }
        }
```

When I do it like this it works.

Which is strange because when I do: `dd($user, user()->user());` both give me a App\Models\User object back...

Anyway I'll just leave this here as is for anybody else facing this problem.

Comment: Please show us the UserController code to be able to help you

Comment: the red squiggly line is your editor, it is not PHP throwing an error ... are you actually getting a PHP error when executing the code?

Comment: I do get an error when I'm executing the code... 'Call to undefined function'.... which is strange because the ```dd($user, auth()->user())``` both give me a user object back...